# Runtime permission check Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, permissions, location

I need my app to ask users to grant permission to access the location.
this is my code in the main activity.cs :

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation) == (int)Permission.Granted);
        
        else {
            if (Android.Support.V4.App.ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation))
            {
                // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
                // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
                // For example if the user has previously denied the permission.
           
            }
            else
            {
                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { Android.Manifest.Permission.Camera }, REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

any help will be great

Comment: Can you clarify what's not working with your code?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the code below to ask for the Location permission in Xamarin.Android.

```
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    public string TAG => "MainActivity";
    View layout;
    //Id to identify a Location permission request.
    static readonly int REQUEST_Location = 0;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        layout = FindViewById(Resource.Id.main_Layout);
        var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        button.Click += Button_Click;
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation) == (int)Permission.Granted)
        {
            // We have permission, go ahead and use the Location.
        }
        else
        {
            // Location permission is not granted. If necessary display rationale & request.
            RequestLocationPermission();
        }
    }       
    void RequestLocationPermission()
    {
        Log.Info(TAG, "Location permission has NOT been granted. Requesting permission.");

        if (ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation))
        {
            // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
            // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
            // For example if the user has previously denied the permission.
            Log.Info(TAG, "Displaying Location permission rationale to provide additional context.");

            var requiredPermissions = new String[] { Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation };
            Snackbar.Make(layout,
                           "Location permission is needed.",
                           Snackbar.LengthIndefinite)
                    .SetAction("OK",
                               new Action<View>(delegate (View obj)
                               {
                                   ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, requiredPermissions, REQUEST_Location);
                               }
                    )
            ).Show();
        }
        else
        {
            // Location permission has not been granted yet. Request it directly.
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation }, REQUEST_Location);
        }
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Any update for this case? Have you solved this issue?